# How to access a field with reverse name = '+' in Django?

Tags: django

How do you define the reverse relation from another object to this one with a '+' as it's related name?

```
class FeaturedContentPage(Page):
    featured_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
```

Comment: The idea of a `+`is to make it unaccessible. Like the documentation says: "*f you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+' or end it with '+'. For example, this will ensure that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model*"

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a `related_name`*ending with a `'+'` is to disable creating a reverse relation, as is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

> If youd prefer Django **not to create a backwards relation**, set related_name to `'+'` or end it with `'+'`.

You can of course still query in reverse with:

```
FeaturedContentPage.objects.filter(featured_page=my_page)
```

But there is thus no relation constructed in reverse, so `my_page.featuredcontentpage_set`is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

the `related_name` argument is used for reverse relation name . if a model has 2 field referencing the same model

```
featured_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
regular_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
```

without `related_name='+'` django will complain because it use `wagtailcore.Page` model name for reverse relation. as two attribute in object can not have same name by setting `related_name='+'` to one or both field will ignore creating reverse relation .